# SQL Performance

Tags: sql

I have tables with data say

**Rolelocation**

```
RL1 CR1 LG1
RL2 CR2 LG2
RL3 CR3 LG3
RL4 CR4 LG4
RL5 CR5 LG1
RL6 CR6 LG1
```

**ContractRole**

```
CR1 Policy1
CR2 Policy1
CR3 Policy1
CR4 Policy1
CR5 Policy2
CR6 Policy2
```

And I wanted to fetch only

```
RL2
RL3
RL4
```

So query I wrote below is working fine but I doubt it will perform well.. Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
SELECT 
    RL.ROLE_LOCATION_ID 
FROM 
    ROLELOCATION RL, contractrole CR
WHERE 
    CR.CONTRACT_ROLE_ID = RL.CONTRACT_ROLE_ID
    AND CR.CONTR_COMPONENT_ID = policy1
    AND RL.LOCATION_GROUP_ID NOT IN (SELECT RL2.LOCATION_GROUP_ID 
                                     FROM ROLELOCATION RL2,CONTRACTROLE CR2 
                                     WHERE RL2.CONTRACT_ROLE_ID = CR2.CONTRACT_ROLE_ID 
                                     AND CR2.CONTR_COMPONENT_ID <> policy1)
```

Comment: post your schema (including indices), and post the result of `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: and if you merely doubt it performs well.. why not test how it performs?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago!)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do the query:

```
select role_location_id
from (SELECT RL.ROLE_LOCATION_ID,
             sum(case when cr.policy <> 'policy1' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by rl.location_group_id) as NumNotPolicy1
      FROM ROLELOCATION RL join
           contractrole CR
           on CR.CONTRACT_ROLE_ID = RL.CONTRACT_ROLE_ID
     ) t
where NumNotPolicy1 = 0
```

This counts the number of times where a non-policy1 appears at the location group level.  It only chooses the rows where this count is 0.